# Why is this MySQL statement working, but the other one isn't?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, wordpress

**Code chunk #1:**

```
    case 'add':
    {
        global $wpdb;
        $message .= $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO projs (compname,projname,imageurl,sumsmall,sumfull,results,caseid,hide) VALUES (" . implode(",", array("'$compname'", "'$projname'", "'$imageurl'", "'$sumsmall'", "'$sumfull'", "'$results'", "$caseid", "$hide")) . ")") 
                    ? 'Successfully added project ' . $projname . ' to the database.'
                    : 'Error occurred when trying to add project to database: ' . $wpdb->last_error;
        break;
    }
```

**Code chunk #2:**

```
    case 'update':
    {
        global $wpdb;
        $message .= $wpdb->query("UPDATE projs SET compname='$compname',projname='$projname',imageurl='$imageurl',sumsmall='$sumsmall',sumfull='$sumfull',results='$results',caseid=$caseid,hide=$hide WHERE id=$id") !== false
                    ? 'Successfully updated project.'
                    : 'Error occurred when trying to update project in database: ' . $wpdb->last_error;
        break;
    }
```

The value of `$hide` is either `0` or `1`. The column `hide` in my MySQL is of type `bool`. Both of my `query`s are working when `$hide` is `1`, but when `$hide` is `0` the first chunk of code, the `'add'` one, isn't working. Why is that??????

Comment: you vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) and what is the value in `$hide`. If it's a php boolean, thena  FALSE in string context becomes an empty string, and you end up doing `... hide= where`.

Comment: Do you get any error messages that might assist us in our quest for the answer?

Comment: could you prove that you send 0 there by `echo "INSERT INTO projs (compname,projname,imageurl,sumsmall,sumfull,results,caseid,hide) VALUES (" . implode(",", array("'$compname'", "'$projname'", "'$imageurl'", "'$sumsmall'", "'$sumfull'", "'$results'", "$caseid", "$hide")) . ")"` please?

Comment: @MarcB This is an application internal to my team, so I don't need to work about attacks

Comment: Because angry employees doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: Malicious or not, any values you get with an apostrophe in them will blow up your queries.